# How do I require something in root project directory from inside node package library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I wanna create a node package modules, but I have difficulty to require a file from root project directory to use inside my node package module I created.

If I have directory structure like this

```
- node_modules
  - library_name
    - lib
      - index.js
    - bin
      - run.sh
-  config.js
```

If the run.sh called, it will run index.js. Inside index.js, how do I resolve to root directory which later I can require config.js inside index.js?

Comment: Why do you need to call an outer script from node_modules folder?

Comment: @JulianSoto Actually I wanna create node package that require some config from root project, it infer the config from nuxt.config.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in `index.js` and `config.js` is in the directory above `node_modules` in your diagram, then you can build a path to `config.js` like this:

```
const path = require('path');
let configFilename = path.join(__dirname, "../../../", "config.js");
```

`__dirname` is the directory that `index.js` is in.

The first `../` takes you up to the `library_name` directory.

The second `../` takes you up to the `node_modules` directory.

The third `../` takes you up to the parent of `node_modules` (what you call project root) where `config.js` appears to be.

---

If you really want your module to be independent of how it is installed or how NPM might change in the future, then you need to somehow pass in the location of the config file in any number of ways:

1. By making sure the current working directory is set to the project root so you can use `process.cwd()` to get access to the config file.
2. By setting an environment variable to the root directory when starting your project.
3. By passing the root directory in to a module constructor function.
4. By loading and passing the config object itself in to a module constructor function.

Comment: Yes, I'd say there's a problem with presupposition. May be ok If the OP is aware of possible implications.

Comment: At the first time, I use the first option. But the second option came into my mind, thats why I ask the question above.

And the second question is is it `process.cwd()` always return root current working directory?

Comment: @JefryDewangga - The current working directory will be whatever the current directory was when you launched node (as long as it was not changed programmatically in your program code).  It is NOT guaranteed to be the root unless you make sure that the way you launch the program makes that be true.  For example, if you are running it from run.sh, then you could `cd` to the proper directory in that script before running node.

Comment: @JefryDewangga - Does this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the best answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.  If not, then please indicate what is not yet answered.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for reminding me on this, yup this answered my question. I've marked that as answered.

Answer (score 5):

Package binary can accept configuration path explicitly as an argument.

If package binary doesn't run as NPM script, it shouldn't rely on parent project structure.

If package binary runs via NPM script:

```
"scripts": {
  "foo": "library_name"
}
```

This will set current working directory to project root, so it could be required as:

```
const config = require(path.join(process.cwd(), 'config'));
```

Both approaches can be combined; this is often used to provide configuration files with default locations to third-party CLI (Mocha, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I create module same your module.

And I call `const config = require('../config')`, it work.